# Why is my compiler expecting a NullPointerException when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, android, oop, methods, nullpointerexception

I have created a `FloatingActionButton` object outside methods without giving it any value. Inside the method `fabInitializer`, I give it a value by referencing it to tag in the XML file. 
When I want to use a method of class's object I've created, Android Studio says:

> object.method() may produce a java null pointer exception.

The program runs fine.

If the object value is `null` it should produce that message, but it is not. How can I fix this?

```java
public void fabInitializer() {
    mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    mFab.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Comment: Hi, please also include the code for the layout XMLs - and it is also more helpful to paste the code text instead of a picture/screenshot.

Comment: As guys pointed out, you can ignore the warning. You can also suppress the warning by clicking ALT+ENTER on top of it and it'll provide you with options on how to 'fix' it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a warning. Android Studio cannot conclude that `mFab` isn't null (since it can be for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null)). If you want to remove the warning and write code more defensively, add a defensive null check:

```
if (mFab!=null) mFab.setOnClickListener(this);
```