# Android ImageView‘s method can not use

Tags: java, android

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp);
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
>                             at com.example.administrator.correct.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:65)

Comment: Your `ImageView` is `null`, because there is no image named `R.id.imageView` in your activity at the time you call `findViewById()`. If you want somebody to help you further, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Provide the code so we can help you, please.

Comment: Or refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null

Comment: <RelativeLayout ...>...

    <ImageView
       ...
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src = "@drawable/helin"
         />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp);

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.RelativeLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.administrator.correct.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, inflated layout has and ImageView that has imageView id.