# ANDROID - Display selected spinner into another activity as textview

Tags: android

> Dont Mark it As Duplicate Question, cz i've been tried to search any possible answer from Stackoverflow sublink

i have 2 spinner in my MainActivity, then i use this code to save it inside `button` `setOnClickListener` code below :

```js
Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pertanyaan.class);
                    i.putExtra("dosen",String.valueOf(sp.getSelectedItem()));
                    i.putExtra("matkul",String.valueOf(sp2.getSelectedItem()));
                    startActivity(i);
```

then in my 2ndActivity, i've tried to call the `key` i've declared like this:

```js
TextView textdosen=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdos);
TextView textmatkul=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmat);
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String dosen=b.get("dosen").toString();
String matkul=b.get("matkul").toString();
textdosen.setText(dosen);
textmatkul.setText(matkul);
```

I've read and find out another Stackoverflow question, and almost of the answer using `PutExtras()`/`PutExtra()` from `intent` to save selected item from spinner, so i've tried it and getting error in my `logcat`

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: flix.yudi.penilaian, PID: 28524
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{flix.yudi.penilaian/flix.yudi.penilaian.Pertanyaan}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at flix.yudi.penilaian.Pertanyaan.onCreate(Pertanyaan.java:45)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

what should i do to fix the error?? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: String dosen=b.getString("dosen");
        String matkul=b.getString("matkul"); replace this

Comment: @Nithinlal still getting the same error sir

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that below are **not null**

```
TextView textdosen=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdos);

TextView textmatkul=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmat);
```

Comment: how to make that `TextView` **not null**?

Comment: i mean please make sure that you have TextViews with  id txtdos and txtmat in the layout of 2ndActivity

Comment: im sure that txtdos and txtmat is declared in layout activity,

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textdosen=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdos);
TextView textmatkul=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmat);

String dosen = getIntent().getStringExtra("dosen");
String matkul = getIntent().getStringExtra("matkul");

textdosen.setText(dosen);
textmatkul.setText(matkul);
```

That's all you need .

Answer (score 0):

In the logcat there is a following line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

which basically means you are calling a `setText` method on a null view.
This could be caused by a number of different reasons. I think you should check out [findViewByID returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null).