# Getting a Spinner's selected item without causing a java.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make an AlertDialog that pops up and has a Spinner in it where someone can select an item, and that item is saved to a variable. However, when I'm testing it out, and I click the OK Button, the app stops, and I get a `java.NullPointerException` on logcat. Apparently, the Spinner's `getSelectedItem()` (which is supposed to get the chosen item) is causing this `java.NullPointerException`.

The code that is causing the NullPointerException:

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                                            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.LanguagePicker);
                                            /*(error is here) -->*/ text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); 



                                            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                                            String r = textInput.getText().toString();
                                            allTheTranslatedText = getTranslatedText(r);
                                            textOutput.setText(allTheTranslatedText);
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();


            }
        });
```

Is there another way you can use retrieve the Spinner's selected item **without** causing a NullPointerException?

Comment: Did you see the follow (realizing it's a bit out of date): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

You are missing promptsView.findViewById();

final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.LanguagePicker);

```
View promptsView = LayoutInflator.inflator(......//do it);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                            //this is the main line
                                            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.LanguagePicker);
                                            /*(error is here) -->*/ text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); 



                                            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                                            String r = textInput.getText().toString();
                                            allTheTranslatedText = getTranslatedText(r);
                                            textOutput.setText(allTheTranslatedText);
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();


            }
        });
```