# Get subview of loaded view (group inside a drawer)

Tags: android

I have a drawer with actions in a group, file a list of files I want to dynamically put in another group. My main activity has this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then the loaded NavigationView is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/test_id">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/group_file_list">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/file1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="File 1"/>
        ...
    </group>

    <item android:title="Actions">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

When I try to get the group where the files are to later add the Items dynamically, all of these return null:

```
findViewById(R.id.group_file_list); // returns null

View navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view); // works
navView.findViewById(R.id.group_file_list); // returns null
navView.findViewById(R.id.test_id); // returns null
```

And yes, I'm calling this after `setContentView()`. I also tried inside `onStart()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do all the items appear on screen?

Comment: Yeah they do now, but using the modified accepted solution that creates a group at runtime instead of using the xml layout

Comment: Ok, so probably they weren’t found initially because they hadn’t been inflated. So, to go your original route I guess you need to force inflate them and then add them as children to R.id.nav_view

Comment: They were visible actually, the group was there and submenu items also. I just couldn't retrieve them. Then F43nd1r proposed to use the menu approach instead but menu items were added at the very end of the menu, outside of the group. Not sure if it's an Android bug

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. However, I still suspect that you will need to add them using manual inflation in order to get the ids to work where you want them to.

Comment: That's very plausible yes, I'm still a bit new to Android. But everything is working ok now, albeit not like I originally wanted it to :)

Comment: Well, if it’s workin for you, there are probably more important things to get used to in android than inflation issues!

Comment: Indeed there is, thanks for your comments, friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to add items to your drawer:

```
NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navView.getMenu().add(...);
```

Or, to add to a group, do this:

```
navView.getMenu().addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, groupName).add(...);
```

See [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getMenu()) and [Menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Yes, I tried that already and it works :) But I need to add a menu item inside the group where all the files are, not on the top level, that's why I'm trying to get group_file_list

Comment: Aw.. wait, just saw in the docs you sent me that you can specify a group id :) I'll try that and check back here!

Comment: It's doing the same when specifying the group as when I wasn't, this adds a menu item at the bottom, not inside the group for files list: navView.getMenu().add(R.id.group_file_list, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "file name");

Comment: Thanks friend, still not working however, getSubMenu() returns null when requesting the R.id.group_file_list. I ended up looking up the docs and finding: navView.getMenu().addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "File list").add("file 1"); You can update your answer and write this then I'll accept since you helped me in the right direction. Really annoys me however that "add" can accept a group id as a parameter but doesn't work at all. Other people have the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Those are menu items and not views. You get them by using the options menu

```
Menu optionsMenu;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       //  store the menu to var when creating options menu
       optionsMenu = menu;
    }
```

Then you can find the item you want

```
MenuItem item = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.test_id);
```

Comment: Thanks friend, however this still returns null, my drawer menu is a ActionBarDrawerToggle, not a top-right OptionsMenu, so it's not inflated in OnCreateOptionsMenu()