# "App keeps stopping" pop ups and give the error java.lang.RuntimeExcpetion

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, runtimeexception

Whenever I run the project on the emulator, it gives me the error App keeps stopping and I can't run the app. There was no error when debugging the code. So I checked on the Logcat then it gives me the error java.lang.RuntimeException. I have no idea where the error is or is it a problem of the code at all? Please someone help me...

1. Main Activity code

   ```
    class MainActivity1 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val circularProgressBar: CircularProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.circularProgressBar)

    circularProgressBar.setProgressWithAnimation(65f,1000)

    findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBarProgress).onProgressChanged{
        circularProgressBar.progress = it
    }
    }
    private fun SeekBar.onProgressChanged(onProgressChanged: (Float)-> Unit){
    setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress : Int, 
    fromUser: Boolean) {
            onProgressChanged(progress.toFloat())
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })
    }
   ```

   }
2. Logcat
   [Image of the Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q981.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setProgressWithAnimation` on a null object. I suggest you not use `findViewById`. Use ViewBinding or at least kotlinx.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm new to this app developing and trying to understand how this works. So may I ask you to explain in more details?

Comment: Would you please give me your main activity XML file? Or you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264610/findviewbyid-returns-null) question as well. Btw in you can read about viewBinding [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Answer (score 0):

This is my main activity xml file. (I don't know if this helps)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.anadroid.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity1"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_header"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            android:text="AkiKomi"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```